# Java eclipse resources?

Tags: java, eclipse, resources

I need som help with using resources in java eclipse. At the moment i am working on a tower defense but i can't load it when i export the runnable jar. since my level file where my map is created can't be loaded as a getFile, how can i change this code.

```
public Level getLevel(String fileName){
        try{
            file = new FileInputStream("level/" + fileName + ".level");
            reader = new InputStreamReader(file);

            scanner = new Scanner(reader);

            level.map = new int[22][18];
```

I am new at devolping and i never really knew about the resource and i can't find a good way to change it now so that it works with resource URL something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the Jar is on classpath, you should try getResource

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("level/" + fileName + ".level"); 
InputStream inputStrm = url.openStream();
```

Comment: Then this catch
 return level;
  } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   
  }
is pretty useless?

Comment: @Sobs Codes in catch depends on what we are doing in `try`. Change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("level/" + fileName + ".level").getFile());
```

[This tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/) describes more